# Block visibility settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, blogs, visibility, drupal-blocks

I'm new at Drupal.

my url is like

> www.blabla.com/drupal/blog/

I have some blocks that must be disabled for blog part. So I go to related block configuration and make it as below:
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100531-1iwfmy1xh54isn5muxj4faha5b.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100531-1iwfmy1xh54isn5muxj4faha5b.jpg)

but it doesnt work :( just to test, I wrote only   *****   , and it worked well. but i doesnt work when I want to define specific page :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
blog
blog/*
```

Comment: i cant believe myself!!!! how silly mistake! I feel like fool :/ Thanks for the reply. it works fine. I just cant believe I missed that point :/

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in taking a look at the [Drupal Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) for handling blocks in a contextual way. It's well worth a look as it makes handling the display rules of blocks a lot simpler. It has a nice UI for setting the context rules and reactions.